# How to customize ItemTouchHelper in RecyclerView Android

Tags: java, android, ontouchlistener, ontouch, itemtouchhelper

I have a RecyclerView where I want to enable **Swipe to Delete/Star on items**. My item is a FrameLayout where a `MaterialCardView` is on the top and the revealed star and archive layouts are under it.

I already made the swipe behavior work using **onTouch** method applied on the CardView only, but it's just way too hard to scroll across the list or use `onClick` or `onLongClick` as onTouch **overrides** them. The only way to scroll the RecyclerView or invoke onClick or onLongClick is to move only in Y axis without moving even a half pixel in X, as moving in X will invoke an `ACTION_MOVE` event that will redirect all next touch events only to the CardView. (`requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent()`) as the first statement of the switch case of ACTION_MOVE).

So I want to apply `ItemTouchHelper` or something similar on the CardView while having the ability to modify the way how the card X changes (To make it slower than user swiping speed like in irremovable notifications in Android) and get the MotionEvent that the user applies, and that's because ***ItemTouchHelper isn't very literal*** about what can be treated as a swipe, so it would allow onClick and onLongClick on small movements, and allow scrolling the list when the movement of Y axis is way greater than X's.

Please don't close this question saying "Too board" like a lot of other questions I had a chance to answer :(

Comment: I can provide codes if needed...